# pyodbc error while inserting data to access database from python gui

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, ms-access-2010, pyodbc

Hi I have received the error below whenever I insert data from my tkinter GUI this error will come up.

I do not have any data type that is AUTONUMBER, and I made sure the value is unique before inserting the data. bottom portion is a screenshot of my data types and fields and source code.

Thanks.

```
def insert():
    fields = date_string.get(), designer_string.get(), recipient_string.get(), wo_string.get(), dateneed_string.get(), sr_string.get(), tcf_string.get(), mun_string.get(), pol_string.get(), address_string.get(), cross_string.get(), desc_string.get()
    for entry in fields:
        if entry == "":
            msgbox.showerror('Error', 'Must Fill All Entry Fields!')
            break
        else:
            insert_data = (
                (date_string.get(), designer_string.get(), recipient_string.get(), wo_string.get(), dateneed_string.get(), sr_string.get(), tcf_string.get(), mun_string.get(), pol_string.get(), address_string.get(), cross_string.get(), desc_string.get())
                )
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testing VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', insert_data)
            conn.commit()
            notif.config(text="WO" + wo_string.get() + " Data Inserted")
            record_display.insert('','end', values = list(insert_data))
        reset()
```

[image: Screenshot]

> IntegrityError: ('23000', '[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again. (-1605) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: It is duplicate error which means that the data you tried to insert into the data has same content in some unique columns as those already in the table.

Comment: "I made sure the value is unique" how did you make sure *all* the index values are unique?

Comment: Also note that `INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ( …` is considered bad form because it assumes that we know the *actual* order of the columns in the table metadata and that is not necessarily the *displayed* order in the table's Design View. Always explicitly name the columns using `INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, … ) VALUES ( …`. Yes, it's more typing but if it saves you from having to track down an obscure bug then it is well worth it.

Comment: It doesn't look like this has anything to do with tkinter.  You could remove the tkinter code and still get this same error with the same  hard-coded data.

Comment: I didn't say it has anything to do with tkinter

Comment: Bryan's right, the python code is not pertinent to your question. The error is saying that this is an issue with the table/keys in your SQL Database, so more information about those, please.